# CakePHP Model Name Uses PHP Reserved Word

Tags: php, cakephp, keyword

Hey I have coded CakePHP for a number of things but never ran into this problem before surprisingly. Also I have thoroughly searched the net and CakePHP docs and have not found an answer to my question. My question is, I have a table for my model that should be named Class, obviously I cannot use that name though since it's a reserved PHP keyword. What options do I have to be able to refer to this model appropriately.

So far I have;

1. Renamed my class model file to player_class.php
2. Renamed my class model class to PlayerClass
3. Changed var $name to 'PlayerClass'
4. Added to my class model class; var $useTable = 'classes';
5. Renamed my class controller to player_classes_controller.php
6. Renamed my class controller class to PlayerClassesController
7. Changed var $name to 'PlayerClasses'

While this does work, is this what has to be done or are to other options to be able to refer to it as Class still, like can I do any sort of mangling like _Class?

Comment: Thanks for the awesome question. Internet just goes off for reserved word usage on CakePHP models problem. You've saved me fiddling around to find a proper solution. Ken is right underscore will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i run into this sort of problem i usually do what you did, only i prefix the reserved word with "My" (so when i read the code it doesn't look like that class has anything to do with "Player"... for example, just the other day i wanted to model a "ACO" model.. but that already existed in cake (same scenario of reserved word) so i created a model called Myaco.

I think you should just name it Myclass.

Regarding the model name and controller name changes- i think you did good, i would do the same. Your only real option is to use the `$useTable = 'classed';` to use your DB table.

If you use the underscore prefix, i believe cake will not be able to handle it (it will fail in the Inflector class).

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's a good idea. My class, "Class", is for a world of warcraft class like warrior, so I may stick with PlayerClass in this instance, I will very likely use that convention in other such cases.

Comment: Just a small observation that's more related to fantasy roleplaying than programming: In Dungeons & Dragons, the full term used is "Character Class" and not "Player Class." Could this be the case in World of Warcraft as well?

Comment: Good observation, that would be the better choice.

Answer (score 5):

I [once](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/sajt/2007/02/25/cake-conventions) tested all CakePHP class names for Cake 1.2 if they can be used as Model names, here are the results:

**NOT possible is:**

```
app
appcontroller
appmodel
behaviorcollection
cache
cacheengine
cakelog
cakesession
classregistry
component
configure
connectionmanager
controller
datasource
debugger
dispatcher
file
fileengine
folder
helper
inflector
model
modelbehavior
object
overloadable
overloadable2
router
security
sessioncomponent
set
string
validation
```

**Possible is:**

```
acl
aclbase
aclbehavior
aclcomponent
aclnode
aclshell
aco
acoaction
admin
ajaxhelper
apcengine
apishell
app_model
apphelper
aro
authcomponent
bake
baker
bakeshell
behavior
cachehelper
cake
cakeschema
cakesocket
consoleshell
containablebehavior
controllertask
cookiecomponent
dbacl
dbaclschema
dbconfigtask
dboadodb
dbodb2
dbofirebird
dbomssql
dbomysql
dbomysqlbase
dbomysqli
dboodbc
dbooracle
dbopostgres
dbosource
dbosqlite
dbosybase
element
emailcomponent
error
errorhandler
extracttask
flay
formhelper
htmlhelper
httpsocket
i18n
i18nmodel
i18nschema
i18nshell
iniacl
javascripthelper
jshelper
jshelperobject
l10n
layout
magicdb
magicfileresource
mediaview
memcacheengine
modeltask
multibyte
numberhelper
page
pagescontroller
paginatorhelper
permission
plugintask
projecttask
requesthandlercomponent
rsshelper
sanitize
scaffold
schema
schemashell
securitycomponent
sessionhelper
sessionsschema
shell
shelldispatcher
test
testsuiteshell
testtask
texthelper
themeview
timehelper
translate
translatebehavior
treebehavior
viewtask
xcacheengine
xml
xmlelement
xmlhelper
xmlmanager
xmlnode
xmltextnode
```

Comment: include `print` in "not possible"

Answer (score 1):

I can second that solution.  I had the same problem and used a prefix that was the initials of the client.  Ended up calling mine Dtclass.  Unfortunately, it took me an hour or so to figure out what the problem was.  One of those cases where the answer stares you in the face all the time till you finally recognize it.